# Get IP logs from google/facebook account

Tags: facebook, geolocation, google-api

How can I retrieve actual IP address and short log of IPs from which is user logged into google/facebook account?

More details:
I need to find out user position (in android APP), but many doesn't use GPS to save battery. Getting position from network is not very accurate. So I thought, I could determine position based on IP, because, when you are at home, you connecting to your gmail/youtoube/... from different IP than when you are at work. Then I can just pair positions with IPs.

Answer (score 1):

If the user connects to **your** server, then you will have their IP address, and you can use a number of different [IP geolocation APIs](http://www.google.com/search?q=IP+geolocation+API) to convert the IP address to a location. Note that IP-based geolocation isn't particularly accurate (it's approximately accurate to the city, but not to anything more fine-grained than that).

You aren't going to get logs from Google, though.

Comment: Thank you, but this isnt a way. I expect users to connect to my server only using mobile app. So if they dont have GPS allowed, and Network location isn't accurate, I wanted to use IP from which they are logged into Google/Faceoob account (IP of pc they use) as additional information. And although the IP doesn't have to be accurate too (I know), If someone is logged from the same IP every Monday-Friday 9:00-16:00 I can pair this IP with work location, and that will be accurate enough.

Comment: If they are connecting to your site from mobile, then you should use the HTML5 geolocation APIs for fine-grained location.

Comment: There's no site, its an android app (sure there will be server side of app in background)... I will use GPS location/ Network location / Wifis detection/ or whatever else is possible, but I wanted to get this logs as some extra info

Comment: If you are creating a new Android app, you can just use the location services on the device to get the user's location: http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationClient.html